# How to calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-n} (\frac{1}{n}+1)^{n^2}$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

How to calculate $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-n} (\frac{1}{n}+1)^{n^2}$$?

The result should be $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$

But I have no idea how to get it.

I've been only thinking of rules to multiply the $e^{-n}$ through somehow, but I don't seem to find anything. The different quantities also seem to work in different directions making interpretation difficult, since:
$$e^{-n}\rightarrow 0$$ 
$$(\frac{1}{n}+1) \rightarrow 1$$
$$n^2 \rightarrow \infty$$

So these interactions make it difficult to say anything about this.

Perhaps there's a way to develop inequalities that show which terms will dominate when approaching infinity?

Comment: As usual, expanding $\log(1+t)=t-t^2/2+o(t^2)$ when $t\to0$ yields the result in a heartbeat.

Comment: Why the lack of personal input and of reaction to comments?

Comment: This does not explain why your question lacks completely of context and why you stay silent when suggestions are made in comments. After 15+ months on the site and 250+ questions asked... :-(

Comment: @Did What context? My question is only about this limit.

Comment: Ah. So you never took care to read any howtoask page on the site? You know, the pages explaining why good questions should have some context / personal input. Glad to know.

Comment: @Did Since I thought it had to have context after all.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(1+1/n)^{n^2}e^{-n}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/422892/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: some ideas with Taylor expansions as the comment says. Put

$$a_n=e^{-n}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}\implies \log a_n=-n+n^2\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=$$

$$=-n+n^2\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

If we take logarithm, we get

$$-n+n^2log(1+\frac{1}{n})$$

$$=-n+n^2(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}(1+\epsilon(n))$$

with $\epsilon(n)$ going to $0$ when

$n \to +\infty$.

thus

the limit is

$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$